# How to automatically show soft keyboard on start?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an activity that only has a EditText. I want the soft keyboard to show up automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this onResume:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_view)),InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

I suggest that you check if there is a Hardware keyboard before you force the keyboard to appear.

To hide:

```
((InputMethodManager) YourActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW).getWindowToken(), 0);
```

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Add a timer to call it 2 or 3 seconds after onResume