# Android - Programmatically Hide/Show Soft Keyboard

Tags: java, android, hide, show, soft-keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do you close/hide the Android soft keyboard programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

First thing first I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) thread. I tried the accepted methods given there, but nothing worked for me.

I have two screens in my app.

- First one has 2 EditText - One for username and one for password
- Second one have one ListView, and an EditText - to filter the
  listView

**In my first screen, I want username EditText to have focus on startup and the Keyboard should be visible**. This is my implementation (simplified by removing unnecessary/unrelated code).

#app_login.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingLeft="20dip"  
    android:paddingRight="20dip">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/username" 
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Username"  
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/password" 
        android:password="true" 
        android:singleLine="true"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:hint="Password" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#AppLogin.java

```
class AppLogin extends Activity{
    private EditText mUserNameEdit = null;
    private EditText mPasswordEdit = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_login);
        
        mUserNameEdit  =    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        mPasswordEdit  =    (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        /* code to show keyboard on startup.this code is not working.*/
        InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(mUserNameEdit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    
    }//End of onCreate()
}
```

Well, **the keyboard is not showing at startup**. And my design badly requires a keyboard there.

Now on to **second page**. As I already mentioned, I have a listView and EditText there. **I want my keyboard to be hidden on startup only to appear when the user touches the editText**. Can you believe it?  whatever I tried **soft Keyboard is showing when I load the activity**. I am not able to hide it.

#app_list_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
   <EditText android:id="@+id/filter_edittext"       
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="Search" android:inputType="text" 
        android:maxLines="1"/>
    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

#AppList.java

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity{
   private EditText mfilterEditText;

    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.app_list_view);

      mFilterEditText  =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filter_edittext);
      InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mFilterEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
   }
}
```

To simplify

1. On Login Page (first Page)  I want my keyboard to be visible on startup.
2. On SecondPage I want the keyboard to be hidden first, only to appear
   when the user touches editText

**And my problem is I am getting the exact opposite on both occasions**. Hope someone faced this issue before. BTW I am testing on the simulator and HTC Desire phone.

#FINAL OUTCOME

Well, I got it working, with the help of all my friends here.

**1. To Show keyboard on startup**

Two answers worked for me. **One provided by @CapDroid, which is to use a handler and post it delayed..**

```
mUserNameEdit.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    keyboard.showSoftInput(mUserNameEdit, 0);
  }
},50);
```

The second answer is provided by @Dyarish, In fact, he linked to another SOF thread, which I haven't seen before. But the funny thing is that this solution is given in the thread which I referenced at the start. And I haven't tried
it out because it had zero votes in a thread where all other posts have plenty of votes. Height of foolishness.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

For me, the second solution looked neat, so I decided to stick with it..But the first one certainly works.
Also, @Dyarish's answer contains a clever hack of using a ScrollView below EditText to give EditText the focus. But I haven't tried it, but it should work. Not neat though.

**2. To hide keyboard at activity start**

Only one answer worked for me, which is provided by @Dyarish. And the solution is to use
focusableInTouchMode settings in XML for the layout containing the EditTexts. This did the trick

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/filter_edittext"       
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="Search" android:inputType="text" 
        android:maxLines="1"/>
    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Anyway, I end up using Dyarish's answer in both cases. So I am awarding the bounty to him. Thanks to all my other friends
who tried to help me.

Comment: @user7777777777 I have edited my question...but not working...I tried with different flags instead of 0 too..

Comment: see my **new update** answer it is working myside...

Comment: The app_login.xml layout does not appear to be the full layout file. Please post the full layout.

Comment: **The app_login.xml layout does not appear to be the full layout file**  Does that matter?

Comment: @krishnabhadra : it works! but I don't get the reason what does focusableintouchmode="true" imply?

Comment: possible your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1109108/779408

Comment: postDelayed work perfect with me

Comment: It can be easily show and hide with convenient methods but there is not an implemented way of catching when user choose to hide it. Due to this limitations I coded a simple snippet that I hope it will be useful. It is available [here](https://felhr85.net/2014/05/04/catch-soft-keyboard-showhidden-events-in-android/). It is pretty easy to use.

Comment: Need to play with InputMethodManager with the INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE to handle soft keyboard like https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/show-hide-android-soft-keyboard/

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Adding this to your code `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` will make sure that your keypad doesn't appear on startup for your edittext box. You want to add this line to your linear layout that contains the EditTextBox. You should be able to play with this to solve both your problems.  I have tested this. Simple solution.

ie: In your app_list_view.xml file

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/filter_edittext"       
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="Search" 
        android:inputType="text" 
        android:maxLines="1"/>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@id/android:list" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

------------------ **EDIT: To Make keyboard appear on startup** -----------------------

This is to make they Keyboard appear on the username edittextbox on startup. All I've done is added an empty Scrollview to the bottom of the .xml file, this puts the first edittext into focus and pops up the keyboard. I admit this is a hack, but I am assuming you just want this to work. I've tested it, and it works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingLeft="20dip"  
    android:paddingRight="20dip">
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/userName" 
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="Username"  
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" 
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
       />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/password" 
        android:password="true" 
        android:singleLine="true"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="Password" />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you are looking for a more eloquent solution, I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100791/how-to-automatically-show-soft-keyboard-on-start) question which might help you out, it is not as simple as the solution above but probably a better solution. I haven't tested it but it apparently works. I think it is similar to the solution you've tried which didn't work for you though.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Cheers!

Comment: Well Dyarish, Your solutions certainly hide the keyboard. Now let me play with this to show keyboard on startup

Comment: Hey Krishnabhadra, I have two potential solutions that should work. The first is kind of a hack, but I've tested this with your code and it works. (I'll admit I don't know why, but it's likely due to properties of this view) I've edited my answer to reflect these solutions. Let me know if this works for you. Cheers.

Comment: Funnily enough, only the `ScrollView` solution worked, I tried the other "more eloquent" solutions and they did not.

Comment: The Scroll View however makes the keyboard appear *only on first startup*, meaning that if you lock the screen then come back, then it will no longer be triggered. As such, I used the following http://stackoverflow.com/a/29229865/2413303 in order to programmatically call the keyboard (with delay, because otherwise it didn't work).

Answer (score 174):

**UPDATE 2**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mUserNameEdit.requestFocus();

        mUserNameEdit.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                keyboard.showSoftInput(mUserNameEdit, 0);
            }
        },200); //use 300 to make it run when coming back from lock screen
    }
```

I tried very hard and found out a solution ... whenever a new activity starts then keyboard cant open but we can use **Runnable** in **onResume** and it is working fine so please try this code and check...

**UPDATE 1**

add this line in your `AppLogin.java`

```
mUserNameEdit.requestFocus();
```

and this line in your `AppList.java`

```
listview.requestFocus()'
```

after this check your application if it is not working then add this line in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<activity android:name=".AppLogin" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
<activity android:name=".AppList" android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"></activity>
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

for hide keyboard

```
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ed.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

for show keyboard

```
 imm.showSoftInput(ed, 0);
```

for focus on EditText

```
 ed.requestFocus();
```

where ed is EditText

Comment: @sHaH well This is the same answer from the thread which I linked in the question, right? The only difference is you tried Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE instead of Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE which I have tried..

Comment: Also I tried as your suggestion and added requestFocus() but to no avail..Anyway thanks for the suggestion..:)

Comment: nope..Not working..Getting frustrated..:(

Comment: Any bug reported about this ?

Comment: I am also trying your code.. and i was shocked .. keyboard isn't open in any activity neither in login nor list..

Comment: Ohhh Man i find out solution check my New Update answer and it will working fine.... :)

Comment: Well your solution certainly works, But can you fathom why it didn't work without this postDelayed?

Comment: i am not sure but may be we cant open keyboard in onCreate() method in activity launcher.....

Comment: Your problem solved dude or not?

Comment: @CapDroid: +1 and Thanks, your code is useful and helped me while viewing..

Comment: add this to your `activity` in the `manifest` file : `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" `

Comment: you can try <public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)> to show up the keyboard, but be aware to check if you got focus for the first time

Comment: To hide keyboard later, use the same code as above, but change one line to `keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);`

Comment: The postDelayed solution works for me too. +1

Comment: do NOT set any flag when show/hide the soft keyboard is the solution to my problem. thanks!

Comment: You need 300 ms of delay to make it *always* be triggered when coming back from lock screen, because 250 for example was not enough as I tried it. But nice answer, this is what eventually worked for me, although I saw this only after I wrote this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29229865/2413303

Comment: For Samsung Galaxy S9 you should use 400ms. And several seconds for future devices. That doesn't look like a good solution.

Answer (score 58):

Try this code.

For showing Softkeyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                                 getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(imm != null){
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
    }
```

For Hiding SoftKeyboard -

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                                  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(imm != null){
        imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure arguments to toggleSoftInput for showing keyboard is right?

Comment: I asked because toggleSoftInput documentation tells first arguement is flag for showing and second argument is flag for hiding..You gave InputMethodManger.SHOW_IMPLICIT as the second argument..Thats why I asked?

Comment: Anyway I tried both ways..nothing worked..

Comment: You can see the answer's that I gave regarding this in my profile it works in the same manner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187137/edittext-keyboard-is-dissappearing/7187321#7187321

Comment: Well I tried bothways..but nothing worked..

Comment: It has to be [imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);] to show so that [imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);] to work for hiding.

Comment: Thanks, works. As Aung Pyae said - make sure when you open keyboard to use toggleSoftInput so you can close it using the same method. If you open keyboard with showSoftInput then closing it with toggleSoftInput will not work.

Comment: This codes worked in every cases. Totally worked. Totally good.

Comment: if you show the keyboard with your code, and then hide it by pressing back, your code won't work correctly anymore.

Answer (score 9):

Did you try `InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT` in first window.

and for hiding in second window use `InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY`

**EDIT :**

 
If its still not working then probably you are putting it at the wrong place. Override `onFinishInflate()` and show/hide there.

```
@override
public void onFinishInflate() {
     /* code to show keyboard on startup */
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(mUserNameEdit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Comment: yes friend..I tried with InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT etc..Also I just passed 0 instead of these constants too..Nothing worked..

Comment: I tried your first edit (showSoftInputFromInputMethod) which didn't work..BTW how to use second method(showSoftInput)?

Comment: **onFinishInflate() of activity class..** I can't find that in the documentation..Infact onFinishInflate is a method in View class..How can I use it here..

Comment: Ok. Try it in `onStart()` or `onWindowFocusChanged()`

Comment: sorry friend, tried that too..But didn't work..