# How to open input Keyboard on load of activity

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` in my activity class. What I want is, whenever my activity starts it automatically opens the input keyboard along with `EditText`. So how that can be done? Please anyone suggest it to me, if possible with example

Comment: is your activity is launcher?

Comment: if your activity is launcher then please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200281/programatically-hide-show-android-soft-keyboard/7200308#7200308) and also read all comment of my answer
..

Comment: Wouldn't `focus()`ing the text box cause the SIP to be displayed automatically? Leaving things to the OS can be good for consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to always show soft keyboard whenever your activity is started, the simplest way is to add this piece of code in your Android Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" />
```

This will just work without you doing anything else with your code.

Comment: yeh its working..but the thing is that in my inputKeyboard "done" button is missing even i give inputtype="textPassword"

Answer (score 1):

add this in your manifest file  this will do

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another method:-

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
// only will trigger it if no physical keyboard is open
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

set this flag in activity's onCreate() method
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);