# How to show/hide the soft keyboard without any animation (e.g. fade) in Java?

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to show or hide the soft keyboard instantly, without any animation?  In Cyanogenmod 10 it displays with a fading animation.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200281/programatically-hide-show-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: What did you find out here? I am trying to get a callback after the hide keyboard animation finishes.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

try like this

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.
                                                    INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Here is no animation disabling