# showing view on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I wrote a small program to evaluate expressions using the set. **But** on the small screen is the following

[With keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQgR4.jpg) and  [without keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqFQs.jpg)

How to fix the Layout Issue?

solved the problem by adding in AndroidManifest.xml line
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`
thx for helping

Comment: put your all layouts in size scrollbar..

Comment: while the lower part will go beyond the screen when adding sets

Comment: Me need that user  see only place where he introduces sets (uses keyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`android:windowSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) attribute of your `<activity />` element in AndroidManifest.xml to control what Android does to your application window when the keyboard is opened.

Answer (score 0):

hide your keyboard:

```
<activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"  />
```

when your app start keyboard is hide. when you touch on edittext then it open.

you can also hide it using:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7200281/1168654) for layouts check all answer.