# Android, how to display keyboard while I'm already using stateHidden?

Tags: java, android, class, keyboard

I have to use stateHidden in Manifest for some reason. But I also need to display keyboard as default for a onCreate(). But whatever I do, the keyboard still not pops-up as default.

I have tried:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(mText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

And:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)mText.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
         inputManager.showSoftInput(mText, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set a listener to FocusChanger and force the request focus with the inputMethodCall.

```
mText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                editText.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(mText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
mText.requestFocus();
```

Check if your manifest is `stateHidden` instead `stateAlwaysHidden`

Comment: Seems that your code contains several errors. Can run n I don't know how to fix it, could you?

Comment: What kind of error you get? What view you wanna show the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200281/programatically-hide-show-android-soft-keyboard) post will help you.
You need to add android:focusableInTouchMode="false" to the main LinearLayout.

Comment: Unfortunately, your one still not work in my case.. I also tried to put it in other layout attributes, still nothing happend.