# Double click on edit text keyboard is showing

Tags: android

I have implemented token `auto complete text view` on `EditText`.
My issue is that I want the keyboard to be shown on a single click on an `EditText` rather than on double click.

```
completionView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if(!hasFocus)
            {
                Log.d("inside>>>>>>>>>>>", "out of focus add");
                InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(completionView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                onFocus();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("et_contacts","focusing to hide");
                onFocus();
            }
        }
    });
    completionView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(completionView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });`
```

Comment: @balajikoduri: please keep in mind inline code spans (`like this`) [shouldn't be used for emphasis](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text), only for code within sentences. Also, please try and improve the post as much as you can when editing a post, it makes other people's lives easier. See the [editing guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) for more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
     completionView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            completionView.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(completionView, 0);
        }
    });
```

write on click `listener` for the edit text and write this code in `onClick()` method.

Comment: what are you doing in onFocus() method.

Comment: that will hide the layouts which is opened...nothing much.

Comment: @asifahmed try this link, it will gives more help ,  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7200308/2633173

Comment: try this for hiding keyboard:  InputMethodManager manger = (InputMethodManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

  manger.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(etAnswer.getWindowToken(),
    InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

Comment: sorry..I'm hiding the keyboard of main activity from the library...how can i do it..how can i get the context of it...

Comment: if you want to hide the keyboard it required a view, then get the context from the view.  like view.getContext();

Comment: if my response is help full to you, accept my answer.