# Hide softkeyboard for locker app

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to close the softkeyboard that is opened in another app.
I tried every solution from here:
[Programmatically Hide/Show Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200281/programatically-hide-show-android-soft-keyboard) or here: [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

As you can see in the pictures i have to close the keyboard opened from another app, adding to manifest to don't make the keyboard visible didn't make the trick.

To note that this is a locker app, i start an activity when the phone goes to sleep mode.

Am i missing something ? Testing other locker apps from store and didn't encountered this problem

But here is the result:

[image: App with opened keyboard]
[image: My app]

Edit: More info

This is how i start the locker:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
    //Toast.makeText(context, "" + "screeen off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    wasScreenOn = false;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LockScreenActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    context.startActivity(intent);

    // do whatever you need to do here
    //wasScreenOn = false;
}
```

This is the manifest code:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.LockScreenActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue. This is how my manifest code for the activity looks like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.LockScreenActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:multiprocess="false"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: I tried this one but no effect. Please let me know if need to do something else excepty this

Comment: @AkarshM I didn't worked for me too, it only worked on some devices, sadly, the project was put on hold so i didn't make any more research

Answer (score 4):

> Try replacing
>   `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing"` with
>   `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` line in
>   `AndroidManifest.xml` like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.LockScreenActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

For reference, you can refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

> "stateHidden" The soft keyboard is hidden when the user chooses the
>   activity — that is, when the user affirmatively navigates forward to
>   the activity, rather than backs into it because of leaving another
>   activity.
>
> "stateAlwaysHidden" The soft keyboard is always hidden when the
>   activity's main window has input focus.

Comment: same issue :( ... the keyboard doesn't hide if i open the keyboard from sms composer or google search. Tried in apps like whatsapp that works, but it worked with my solution too :(

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved overriding `onPause()` of this activity and use following piece of code as

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (null != getWindow()){
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: does not hide the soft keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Activity:

```
private void hideKeyboard() {   
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard/7696791#7696791

Comment: Doesn't work because the view that has the focus is not the view that has opened the softkeyboard. The softkeyboard is opened in another app.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(
                        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I don't have any edit text in my view. The edit text is in another app that is independent from my app

Comment: hi please check my edited ans, added a useful link hope it will helps you