# Using both soft keyboard and physical keyboard in Android app

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyboard

is there a way to force soft keyboard in Android 4.4 app?

I'm developing an app which needs both software keyboard and bluetooth barcode reader. Barcode reader will be used in 99% of cases, but there are some options which require soft keyboard (e.g. typing e-mail address or password).

When barcode reader is paired with the phone, soft keyboard doesn't appear. I'd like to keep it that way, but when user enters a selected view soft keyboard should appear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are looking to hide and show the soft keyboard when needed, look at these already asked questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200281/programatically-hide-show-android-soft-keyboard, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work when BT barcode scanner is connected. When it's connected soft keyboard is always hidden

Comment: @pioand Did you find any solution?