# How to keep the software keyboard in Android from hiding after a TextBox loses focus in Uno Platform?

Tags: uno-platform

I have a `TextBox` and a `Button`. When the button is clicked, the `TextBox` loses focus and the keyboard hides. How do I keep the keyboard from hiding when the button is clicked?

I first thought to use `AllowFocusOnInteraction`, but this is not supported on Android at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `AllowFocusOnInteraction` isn't implemented, [`Control.IsTabStop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.istabstop?view=winrt-19041) is. `IsTabStop` likewise prevents the control from receiving focus. Use `IsTabStop` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Uno Platform is using the Android input behavior here, so when the input loses focus, the programmatic keyboard automatically disappears. However, if you want to show it again immediately, you can give it focus again from within the button `Click` handler.

XAML:

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="InputBox" />
<Button Click="TestClick">Test</Button>
```

C#:

```cs
private void TestClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InputBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

The input pane starts disappearing, but is immediately requested again, so it is almost imperceptible.

You can also try to trigger the soft keyboard programmatically without having any `TextBox` in place, by writing platform-specific code. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7200308/732221) for example includes quite a few solutions for Android. In general, they utilize the `INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE` and call `ShowSoftInput` on it.

Comment: Thank you for the info! I was previously giving focus back to the TextBox, but it would make the keyboard jitter. Using IsTabStop seems like the most straightforward to overcome this at this time.